# Rails asset pipeline not compiling image for select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, jquery-select2

I'm using the Select2 plugin in my one of my Rails 3.2 projects. It's currently residing in the directory `vendor/assets/javascript/select2/` (all the js, css and image files are in here, in the same locations as they were unzipped from the downloaded plugin).

I've included the select2 css and javascript files in my application.css and application.js files as expected:

```
application.css
 *= require select2/select2

application.js
//= require select2/select2.min
```

But now that I've deployed to production, the `select2.css` file is looking for `assets/select2.png`, when the image in question is actually located at `assets/select2/select2.png`.

How to I get the image to compile down into the right location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) gem to solve issues with asset pipeline.

BTW: Rails 4 no longer compile assets from lib/assets and vendor/assets by default: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7968

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by moving the `select2.png` image into the `vendor/assets/images` directory. I had hoped to avoid this (I'd prefer to leave all the select2 stuff together for easier upgrading to new versions), but if it works it's hard to argue.